# Read from large MongoDB, write to JSON

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have a MongoDB with about 70gb of data in it. I need to download the entire DB into one JSON document, preferably with Python. However, when I try and do `json.dump(object, file_object)` a couple million times, I tend to unintentionally create a malformed JSON. Storing the entire DB in memory isn't an option, because, well, 70gb > 16gb of RAM. How can I write JSON documents, one at a time, to the same file object in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use mongoexport to export the data:

```
mongoexport --db test --collection traffic --out traffic.json
```